# Combining Strings without '+'

Tags: javascript, string

I come from python & if I want to print this line "Hello World" I can do this:

```
line = "Hello %s" % "World"
```

How can I combine string templates with my variables like the above?

IE, I want to combine this

```
var arrray = new Array( "a", "b", "c" );
var template = "<option> %s </option>";

for ( var i in array )
{
    alert( template % i ); // should show "<option> a </option>" & so on
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-printf-string-format

Answer (score 4):

There's [sprintf() for JavaScript](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf).

Answer (score 0):

Not addressing your root question, but a different (more flexible) approach to your example problem, using an [**MVVM framework**](http://knockoutjs.com/):

```
<select data-bind="options: items"></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        items: ko.observableArray(["a", "b", "c"])
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

This will accomplish all sorts of magical things, such as automatic/realtime binding, so when you add or remove elements from the array in the viewmodel, the `<select>` options automatically reflect that.